# How to pad with n characters in Python

Tags: python, string

I should deﬁne a function `pad_with_n_chars(s, n, c)` that takes a
string 's', an integer 'n', and a character 'c' and returns
a string consisting of 's' padded with 'c' to create a
string with a centered 's' of length 'n'. For example,
`pad_with_n_chars(”dog”, 5, ”x”)` should return the
string "`xdogx`".

Comment: The actual solution to the problem is definitely important. But equally important is the detection and handling of erroneous input.  Think about your 3 input arguments, and see if you can antcipate what values of each would cause problems for your `pad_with_n_chars` function.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

With Python2.6 or better, there's no need to define your own function; the string [format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method can do all this for you:

```
In [18]: '{s:{c}^{n}}'.format(s='dog',n=5,c='x')
Out[18]: 'xdogx'
```

Using f-string: `f'{"dog":x^5}'`

Comment: +1. Please note that format is quite recent and probably won't work with legacy Python versions.

Comment: It's also possible to specify the width and the fill character inline: `'{:x^5}'.format('dog')`

Comment: It is also possible to chain several rules. `"{:#^10.0%}".format(0.234)` would output `'###23%####'`. Where "#^10" is the centering and padding definition, and ".0%" is the percent formater.

Answer (score 52):

yeah just use ljust or rjust to left-justify (pad right) and right-justify (pad left) with any given character.

For example ... to make '111' a 5 digit string padded with 'x'es

In Python3.6:

```
>>> '111'.ljust(5, 'x')
111xx

>>> '111'.rjust(5, 'x')
xx111
```

Answer (score 27):

It looks like you're only looking for pointers, not a complete solution. So here's one:

You can multiply strings in python:

```
>>> "A" * 4
'AAAA'
```

Additionally I would use better names, instead of *s* I'd use *text*, which is much clearer. Even if your current professor (I suppose you're learning Python in university.) uses such horrible abbreviations.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.x there are string methods: `ljust`, `rjust` and `center`.

I created a function:

```
def header(txt: str, width=45, filler='-', align='c'):
    assert align in 'lcr'
    return {'l': txt.ljust, 'c': txt.center, 'r': txt.rjust}[align](width, filler)

print(header("Hello World"))
print(header("Hello World", align='l'))
print(header("Hello World", align='r'))
```

Output:

```
-----------------Hello World-----------------
Hello World----------------------------------
----------------------------------Hello World
```

Comment: I like it, but having other language background, I didn't immediately understand how it works. For those like me I explain: return {...} part is dictionary that maps align key like 'c' to a function pointer like txt.center. After that function pointer is selected by [align] and then invoked by providing arguments (width, filler)

Answer (score 2):

well, since this is a homework question, you probably won't understand what's going on if you use the "batteries" that are included.

```
def pad_with_n_chars(s, n, c):
    r=n - len(s)
    if r%2==0:
       pad=r/2*c
       return pad + s + pad
    else:
       print "what to do if odd ? "
       #return 1
print pad_with_n_chars("doggy",9,"y")
```

Alternatively, when you are not schooling anymore.

```
>>> "dog".center(5,"x")
'xdogx'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print '=' * 60
header = lambda x: '%s%s%s' % ('=' * (abs(int(len(x)) - 60) / 2 ),x,'=' * (abs(int(len(x)) - 60) / 2 ) )
print header("Bayors")
```