# What is the niceset way of padding \n or any chars to a string?

Tags: python, string, padding

I have some long strings, `fooo`, `barxxxx\n`. How can I output the strings with a single \n at the end? Of course I can do

```
def padWithReturn(s):

    if not s.endswith('\n'):
        s+='\n'

    return s

padWithReturn('fooo')
```

but it feels awkward.

I read about [How to pad with n characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008546/how-to-pad-with-n-characters-in-python).
Is there a similar elegant way of doing this, using `.format()`?

edit : I have over 1000000 lines of text to process. It's a single maya .ma file. will this be slow ?
`s.rstrip('\n')+'\n'`
or should i use the if else expression, both seem to be too computational intensive ? (haven't tested yet) my hunch tells me if else condition will be faster because it deals with less string ?

Comment: if it's only a 1-time thing, even if you have over a million lines, it doesn't really matter what approach you take.  As far as what is fastest in general, It's hard to say.  It could be line-length dependent (or maybe not).  You'd need to `timeit` on real data to find out.

Comment: You say that you have 100000 _lines_ to process; so how are you identifying a line if it doesn't have a newline character? Or are you reading in one long line (again, wondering how you are determining where a line ends and the other begins), splitting it up into multiple chunks, then writing these chunks out - each with one newline character at the end?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i have newline char for each line, but i may read several lines and do some concatenation, then the \n is removed during the process.

Comment: Why not rstrip() those that you need to concatenate, and leave the others as-is? Their existing end-of-line character will be preserved.

Answer (score 3):

A function seems a little overkill here since it can boil down to a single expression:

```
s if s.endswith('\n') else s + '\n'
```

Of course, you always *can* wrap this in a function if you so desire...

Comment: @thefourtheye -- I was wondering the same thing :).  If the downvoter care to comment, I'll happily try to address the issue by clarifying my response...

Comment: i feel classic way is simply the best way in this case ? or maybe `s.rstrip('\n')+'\n'`

Comment: @Shuman -- Yeah, that does extra work if you don't have to (albiet probably negligible).  The biggest downside is if you have a string which ends with 2 `\n`, it'll be replaced with only 1.  Maybe that's what OP wants, maybe not ...

Answer (score 1):

Using format, you would do it like this:

```
if not s.endswith('\n'):
    return '{}\n'.format(s)
```

Comment: You can simplify this to `return '{}\n'.format(s.rstrip('\n'))`

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just remove the newline, and then tack it on again.

```
def pad_with_newline(s):
    return s.rstrip('\n') + '\n'
```

Note: If you have multiple newlines on the end of a string, this will remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional expression:

```
def padWithReturn(s):
    return '{}{}'.format(s, '' if s.endswith('\n') else '\n')
```

or

```
def padWithReturn(s):
    return '{}{}'.format(s, '\n'[s.endswith('\n'):])
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this:

```
def padWithReturn(a):
    if a[-1:] != '\n' : a += '\n'
    return a
```