# How to pad leading zeros to the Time column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Using `'df_dropped'`, a data frame, which has a column `'Time'`.

```
df_dropped['Time'] = df_dropped['Time'].apply(lambda x:'{:0>4}'.format(x))
```

I don't understand what the `'{:0>4}'.format(x)'` does.
Please explain the construction of this line `'{:0>4}'.format(x)'`

Comment: What you are looking for might be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008546/how-to-pad-with-n-characters-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pad with n characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008546/how-to-pad-with-n-characters-in-python)

Comment: Explained here:- https://datacamp-global.slack.com/archives/C654VRAJ2/p1542346188142800?thread_ts=1542341652.142000&cid=C654VRAJ2

Answer (score 2):

It adds 0 character to each elements of data-frame until it reach 4 character. If the element is more than 4 character will do nothing.
you can see below example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[23, "fsda", 289801, 87], columns=['Time'], index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: '{:0>6}'.format(x))
```

Comment: '{:0>6}'.format(x)  can you explain this bit of code