# Append to string up to given value

Tags: python, append

I have created a user input variable asking for a string.  If the string contains less than 7 letters, I want to append the letter "X" to the end of the string.  But the number of X's need to take the total length of the string up to 7.

So for example, if the user enters "apple", I would want to display this as appleXX.  If they enter "dog", I want this to display dogXXXX.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: And what should happen if the entered string is longer than 7 characters?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438719/2055998).